# Typescript module resolving 'rxjs' differently in the same file

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, rxjs

I've spent hours going around in circles, so time for another obscure question.

I'm inside a `lerna` mono repo, with two sub projects, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`.

`ProjectA` has a dependency on `rxjs`, as does `ProjectB`.

`ProjectB` has a dependency on `ProjectA` which `lerna` manages by using symlinks.

The problem is, in `ProjectB`, I have a file which does the following imports:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
```

In that file, there is a class which has a private variable which is a `Subject`, and it exposes it as a `Observable`. However, tsc is complaining with the following error:

> Type '`Subject<ActionRequestResult<any>>`' is not assignable to type '`Observable<ActionRequestResult<any>>`'.
>     Property 'source' is protected but type '`Observable<T>`' is not a class derived from '`Observable<T>`'.

After investigating, it turns out the two `rxjs` imports at the top of the file are actually being imported from two different locations. So even though `Subject` extends `Observable`, it is not the same `Observable` that is being imported and referenced in my file.

I attempted to install `rxjs` at the root project level, where the `lerna.json` file is located. But `ProjectB` has a dependency on `webpack-cli` which has a transitive dependency on `rxjs` as well, so it still gets installed into `ProjectB`.

So I'm not exactly sure where to go, or if this is a bug or not?

`ProjectA` uses `Subject` internally, so I suspect typescript is walking the project tree and caching where each thing is, and this is breaking in the situation I am in.

Any thoughts or advice?

Comment: Usually this kind of issues is solved with configuring tsconfig.json paths param

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by switching the order of my import statements. I believe this is a bug related to the Typescript language service and the way it's caching things. I'll submit an issue soon.

Basically, I had the this:

```
import { Something } from 'ProjectA';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
```

Because `ProjectA` referenced `Subject`, the language service evidently caches that, so when I import that myself, it uses the reference it already has.

Moving the `ProjectA` import to the end resolved the issue:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Something } from 'ProjectA';
```